# How to return embedded document with ID of

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo

I have a MongoDB collection with an example document like this:

[image: Mongo example document]

What I want to do (as you can see from the actual code) is to update a `role` field in `members.x.role` where `members.x.id` equals given ID (ID is UUID so it's unique; this part of code works without problem) and then I want to return that `members.x`. But the problem is that it always returns first member instead of the one that has been just updated. I've tried some methods of *mgo* and found `Distinct()` be closest to my expectations, but that doesn't work as I want.

My question is how can I return `member` ***embedded document*** with specified ID?

I've already looked on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9201743/mongodb-select-field-to-return-embedded-document-in-array) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33751451/how-can-i-use-mongodb-projections-with-go-and-mgo) but it didn't help me.

```
func (r MongoRepository) UpdateMemberRole(id string, role int8) (*Member, error) {
    memberQuery := &bson.M{"members": &bson.M{"$elemMatch": &bson.M{"id": id}}}
    change := &bson.M{"members.$.role": role}

    err := r.db.C("groups").Update(memberQuery, &bson.M{"$set": &change})
    if err == mgo.ErrNotFound {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("member with ID '%s' does not exist", id)
    }

    // FIXME: Retrieve this member from query below. THIS ALWAYS RETURNS FIRST MEMBER!!!
    var member []Member
    r.db.C("groups").Find(&bson.M{"members.id": id}).Distinct("members.0", &member)

    return &member[0], nil
}
```

Comment: did you use `{new: true}` in update query

Comment: @AshishChoudhary no, why? there's no problem with updating, the problem is with retrieving this specific embedded document

Comment: you have mentioned that you want updated data ... right??

Comment: you're right, can you link me any resource of what that `new` will do? I didn't hear of that

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32811510/mongoose-findoneandupdate-doesnt-return-updated-document

Comment: {new: true} if set true then will return the updated docs... else return previous data

Comment: this actually won't help me because it returns whole document which I already have, but I found a workaround

Comment: ok... so do you want specific keys???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround, it's not stricte Mongo query that is returning this embedded document, but this code is IMO more clear and understandable than some fancy Mongo query that fetches whole document anyway.

```
func (r MongoRepository) UpdateMemberRole(id string, role int8) (*Member, error) {
    change := mgo.Change{
        Update: bson.M{"$set": bson.M{"members.$.role": role}},
        ReturnNew: true,
    }

    var updatedGroup Group
    _, err := r.db.C("groups").Find(bson.M{"members": bson.M{"$elemMatch": bson.M{"id": id}}}).Apply(change, &updatedGroup)
    if err == mgo.ErrNotFound {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("member with ID '%s' does not exist", id)
    } else if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    for _, member := range updatedGroup.Members {
        if member.Id == id {
            return &member, nil
        }
    }

    return nil, fmt.Errorf("weird error, Id cannot be found")
}
```